# Recyclerview doesn't show list of data from Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a activity which is use to make a receipt. The Activity have a alertdialog in it, the use of this alertdialog is to add List data of item that will be added to Receipt. I already make the code and it runs but the problem is when I add item from the alert dialog, it doesn't show in the Activity/Receipt RecyclerView.

can somebody fix this code ?

Code:

```
public class CreateReceiptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.btn_receipt_add_item)
    ImageButton addItem;
    @BindView(R.id.receipt_view_recycler)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    List<ListReceiptItem> receiptItemList;
    ListReceiptItem listReceiptItem;
    ReceiptItemAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_receipt);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        receiptItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new ReceiptItemAdapter(this, receiptItemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater li = CreateReceiptActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

                View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_create_receipt, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateReceiptActivity.this);
                builder.setView(v);

                final EditText addItemType = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_type);
                final EditText addItemQty = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_qty);
                final EditText addItemPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_price);
                Button btnSubmit = v.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_receipt_submit);



                final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.show();
//
//                receiptItemList = new ArrayList<>();
//                listReceiptItem = new ListReceiptItem();
                btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        final String itemType = addItemType.getText().toString();
                        final String itemQty = addItemQty.getText().toString();
                        final String itemPrice = addItemPrice.getText().toString();
                        listReceiptItem = new ListReceiptItem(itemType, itemQty, itemPrice,"0");
                        receiptItemList.add(listReceiptItem);
                        adapter = new ReceiptItemAdapter(CreateReceiptActivity.this, receiptItemList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an adapter in the activity then no need to reinitialise adapter again. Remove this code from buttonClick

```
adapter = new ReceiptItemAdapter(CreateReceiptActivity.this, receiptItemList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After adding new item on the list just notify the adapter. Like this

```
receiptItemList.add(listReceiptItem);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: the recycler view still doesn't show anything, any idea why ?

Comment: Would you please share your adapter class?

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines in OnClickListener event

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` inside onclick listener.

Comment: What Faysal suggested is the proper way to communicate with adapter. Unfortunately in your code you are passing information about "receiptItemList" only though the adapter constructor. In this case if you remove your original code inside button click, I am afraid that may not serve the purpose.